# Count for every 'x' that falls into an interval within a given time range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, intervals

I'm looking to get a headcount of people available every hour within a time frame.

| Employee | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp name | 8:30 AM | 10:30 AM |
| Emp name | 8:30 AM | 10:45 AM |
| Emp name | 8:00 AM | 10:15 AM |

If I were to take a count of employees available at 9:45 AM, I should get 3. Or maybe I want 15 minute intervals and want to know my headcount at 8:15, which would be 1.

Currently my solution is to make a table for every hour in a day using the following formula to add a tally for every hour an employee is available:

```
=IF(AND($G9>=R$1,$G9<S$1),1,IF(AND(R$1>$G9,R$1<$H9),1,""))
```

And i get something that looks like this:

| Start Time | End Time |  | 8:00 AM | 9:00 AM | 10:00 AM | 11:00 AM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:30 AM | 10:30 AM |  |  | 1 | 1 |  |

Finally I can pivot this or countif it to get my total.

Is there a more elegant solution to this? Preferably one that allows me to change the interval but still gives me an accurate count. Even better if I don't need to build out the interval table.

I'm open to using VBA or formulas.

Overall, what is this problem called? I'd like to look up a pythonic solution on my own time for some self study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every line represents a different employee, then just use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,"<="&E2,C:C,">="&E2)
```

[image]